# Should I instantiate new objects for all different interactions?

Tags: php, oop

Im having a hard time grasping this concepts of objects and how they should interact/exist.

Should I for instance have different objects (well, maybee I mean connections to the database here if there is any difference) for interactions with my database whenever they are not related?

Lets say I have one object that index.php uses to get and display content from the database 
and another object that a user use to add/remove things in the database. We can say that the objects are all of the class dbinteract which holds all the functions for messing about with the database.

Or should I maybee divide the classes into something like: dbconnection, dbdisplay, dbinsertion, dbmodification where I send the dbconnection to the other objects?

I feel like im missing something very obvious and it's frustrating trying to move forward not knowing where in the thought process im going wrong, I guess im looking for a question as well as a an answer here.

### index.php

```
$connection = new dbconnection();
$displayer = new dbdisplay();

$activeconnection = $connection->connecttodatabase();
$pagetodisplay = $connection->getcontentofpagetodisplay($query);
$displayer->displayPage($activeconnection, $pagetodisplay);
```

### userinsert.php

```
$inserter = new dbinsert();
$usersdbconnection = new dbconnection();

$inserter->newPost($userdbconnection, $usercredentials, $posttextfromuser);
$usersdbconnection->closedatabaseconnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be think at the wrong level of abstraction. OOP allows you to think about 'users' and 'articles' instead of 'database connections' and 'pages'.

I'm not sure I understand the problem fully - I think your question is 'which object should be responsible for connecting to the database?'. Creating a connection to the database only needs to be done once. This connection can then be shared between all of the objects. To share the connection you will need to create a class which all other classes that connect to the database can inherit from and a `static` variable in that class to ensure that only one connection object exists.

In other languages `static` variables are commonly called `class` variables.

Comment: So having an open connection to the database at all times isnt a problem? 
Could I then have like a "database" object with the static connection variable which has the database connection and then a "article" object that extends database with functions like getArticle($query), displayArticle() and then a "user" object that also extends the "database" object with functions like insertArticle(), modifyArticle(), deleteArticle()? Or did you mean it some other way?

Comment: @Bojrklund: Yes, that's how I would solve the problem. Make sure you close the connection when your script exits. You can do this by implementing `__destruct` method in your `database` class.

Answer (score 1):

To me, what it seems like you're missing is that object-oriented programming isn't there to make you do extra work following its rules, it's there to make your life easier.  If it isn't making your life easier, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes books are better then surfing the net
i found this book really useful. 
the examples lean towards java, but can be applied to any language

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008673/